# e.CenterItemIndex turns to 0, each time group is change (OS)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.collectionview

I am using Scrolled event in `collectionView` for iOS. If `CollectionView` contains groups, `e.CenterItemIndex` turns to 0 each time group is changing.
Is there any way i can fix this?

```
private void CollectionViewtems_Scrolled(object sender, ItemsViewScrolledEventArgs e)
{
    var centerItemIndex=e.CenterItemIndex;
}
```

On iOs: When a group of `collectionView` will change it starts from 0 again;
Example while Scrolling on iOS:

```
Index is 0
Index is 1
Index is 2
Index is 3
Index is 4
Index is 5  //After that index group will change 
Index is 0
Index is 1
Index is 2 //And after that index group will change again
Index is 0
Index is 1
Index is 2
Index is 3
Index is 4
```

In other hand on Android index will have a continous increment

```
Index is 0
Index is 1
Index is 2
Index is 3
Index is 4
Index is 5  //After that index group will change 
Index is 6
Index is 7
Index is 8 //And after that index group will change again
Index is 9
Index is 10
Index is 11
Index is 12
Index is 13
```

Comment: you need to include the relevant code in the body of your post if you expect anyone to help you

Comment: Plaease check my modified answer

Comment: What do you mean by  "group is changing" ?

Comment: I mean GroupHeader Template in collectionView

Comment: Do you mean you scroll the list,then the centerItemIndex starts from 0 again ?

Comment: Thank you Leo Zhu. Exactly, while i am scrolling centerItemIndex starts from 0 again, when group is changes

Comment: Could you show a gif or screenshot ?That would be clearer.